# Send newsletter with php variable in it

Tags: php, email, newsletter

Hope someone can help me.
I want to send newsletter with php, and to put some values from my database in it. I can build html mail but i can't put php variables in it. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$subject = "Newsletter";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "to@mail.com";
$name = "Firstname Lastname";
$contactEmail = "contact@mail.com";
$message = "message";

$htmlContent = '
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>test</p>
<p>$name</p>
<p>$contactEmail</p>

<p>$message</p>
</body>
</html>
';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: from@mail.com' . "\r\n";

  if(mail ($to, $subject, $htmlContent, $headers))
    {
        $successMessage = "Newsletter is sent.";
    } else {
        $messageError ="There is an error with your newsletter.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: variables don't get parsed in single quotes

Comment: `$htmlContent = "<p>test</p><p>$name</p>\n$contactEmail\n$message";`

Comment: I dont see any database access in your code

Comment: I want to buld variable that access my databse record so i can put it in newslater, but i cant get any php variable in my newsletter, ill try to put it in single quotes and ill see if it will work. Thanks a lot